# Problemas con metodo de cifrado en Py3.4 puro

Tags: python, encriptación, python-3.4

Primero que nada: soy nuevo en stackoverflow asi que podria cometer algunos errores.

El problema entra en accion es cuando "Decript" requiere sumar la pareja de caracteres 255 con 49, Y no podria en ese caso (Bueno tecnicamente si, Pero depènde del SO!), Y obiamente lo corromperia.

Tambien pasaria exactamente lo mismo en el caso contrario, Si se requiere sumar el caracter 49 con el caracter 255.

Aqui un ejemplo real:

```py
Python 3.4.1
>>> Data=Encript(b"Hola Mundo",1234)
>>> Data
b'y\xa1\x9f\x95Q\x7f\xa8\xa2\x95\xa1'
>>> Decript(Data,1234)
b'Hola Mundo'
>>> with open("FotoDeEjemplo.jpg","rb") as r, \
...     open("FotoDeEjemplo2.jpg","wb") as w:
...   Data=Encript(r.read(),1234) # Hasta aqui Ok
...   w.write(Decript(Data,1234)) # Y aqui empezamos con el problema
```

El codigo es este:

```py
def _Generator(Key):
  while 1:
    for k in str(Key): yield ord(k)
    
def Encript(Data,Key):
  Result=[]
  for b,k in zip(Data,_Generator(Key)):
    Result.append(b+k)
  return bytes(Result)

def Decript(Data,Key):
  Result=[]
  for b,k in zip(Data,_Generator(Key)):
    Result.append(b-k)
  return bytes(Result)
```

¿Alguna idea de como solucionar o aun que sea mejorarlo?

EDITO:
Hay alguna forma de optimizar este metodo de cifrado o ya esta en su tope?

Comment: Haz módulo 256 para quedarte con el resto. Es decir `(b+k)%256`

Comment: Wooww mil gracias @abulafia , la verdad nunca se me ocurrio usar el resto.

Comment: @abulafia como se cierra el post?, como dije Linea 1, "Primero que nada: soy nuevo en stackoverflow asi que podria cometer algunos errores."

Comment: Bueno, tienes dos formas. Puedes borrar la pregunta si crees que no es interesante para nadie más, o puedes escribir tú mismo una respuesta (explicando un poco cómo funciona) para así contribuir al sitio y a quienes puedan tener una duda similar. Pasado un tiempo puedes incluso aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Comment: Nuevamente muchas gracias, encontre un pequeño detalle en `(b+k)%256` deberia ser 255, Aun que me quedo extrañado ya que segun google me dice que el limite del ascii es 256 pero en algunos SO el limite es 255. por eso digo "deberia"

Comment: El máximo valor representable en un byte es efectivamente 255, pero por eso la división se hace entre 256. El resto de esa división será un número entre 0 y 255.

Comment: Ufff perdoname, Tenes toda la razon. Me confundi con unas de las pruebas que estaba haciendo. Probe pasando en valor un 255 y clave 255, Y me dio un bug, **pero vuelvo y repito fue que confundi unas de las pruebas**. Asi que olvida el comentario anterior al tuyo @abulafia

Answer (score 0):

Encript(v2.0)

Puede parecer mas engorroso de manejar y mas codigo y/o un poco menos legible, Pero cuando quieras usarlo paso por paso(Por ejem. Una barra de progreso) ...

Ademas ya esta optimizado para no malgastar tanto uso del CPU y tiempo, Gracias al sistema de Cache.

```py
def _Generator(Key): # Se usa para no tener que malgastar la RAM por usar "Key=Key*len(Data)"
  while 1:
    for k in str(Key): yield ord(k)

def Encript(Data,Key,_BUFF=1024*7): # 7 KB
  Cache=[]
  i=0
  for b,k in zip(Data,_Generator(Key)):
    if i>_BUFF:
      i=0
      yield bytes(Cache)
      Cache.clear()
    Cache.append((b-k)%256)
    i+=1

def Decript(Data,Key,_BUFF=1024*7): # 7 KB
  Cache=[]
  i=0
  for b,k in zip(Data,_Generator(Key)):
    if i>_BUFF:
      i=0
      yield bytes(Cache)
      Cache.clear()
    Cache.append((b+k)%256)
    i+=1

if __name__=="__main__":
  Data=b"".join(
        Encript(b"Hola Mundo",chr(255))
  )
  print(Data) # b'Ipmb!Nvoep'
  Data=b"".join(
        Decript(Data,chr(255))
  )
  print(Data) # b'Hola Mundo'
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a SOes. Bien por elegir responder tu propia pregunta. Pero en general, en este sitio, una respuesta debería incluir algo más que el código. Una breve explicación de qué se ha añadido, por qué funciona... de este modo la respuesta es más útil y recibe votos positivos.